# Blocked over question about random numbers

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, quality-improvement

I was blocked for this question: [Random Number Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089327/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-generate-random-numbers-in-a-predefined-start). I know many methods to create random numbers. But, and this was the core of my intention, I am looking for a method to create random numbers with the option to define a start range and a end range - and possibly the range for the "middle section". I was looking for a smooth and random looking dissolve from one range to another range. Admin's comment:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details

But what should I say? There are no more details! ;) How could I describe it in a better way? The following picture describes it, to my understanding, crystal clear:

[image: Dissolve Random Number Range]

Comment: You want to solve that for a specific programming language? So you probably need to show some attempts you made with it.

Comment: It was posted with [tag:r] @πάνταῥεῖ. Not that I understand completely what this is about...the pictures make it more confusing. I _think_ the OP wants to create random sets of co-ordinates within a 2 dimensional space, but the x axis doesn't look like it's got much randomness to it.

Comment: *This picture name it, from my understanding, crystal clear.* Excellent. Since a picture is worth a thousand words, please go and write those thousand words into a clear, on-topic question. As Ben says, the picture gives just enough information to make your requirements less clear.

Comment: `
a <- rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 3)
b <- rnorm(100, mean = 25, sd = 5)
c <- rnorm(100, mean = 18, sd = 1)
d <- c(a, b, c)
plot(d)
`

Comment: @Teletubbi-OSX Ah! That clarifies everything! Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089327/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-generate-random-numbers-in-a-predefined-start) did have nice pictures, but it had one fatal flaw:

### It did not ask an actual question!

You literally started your question with the phrase

> e.g 100 random numbers with different start and end ranges.

and then this picture. There was another picture, too, which was different than the first one, and maybe it's because I don't know any R and mostly slept through the one stats class that I did take, but I cannot understand what these pictures are showing and how they make sense together.

And don't take my word for it. Three out of the five people that voted to close your question hold gold tag badges in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) (the other two have silver tag badges), so they obviously know what they're doing. They're not like me, with no knowledge about R.

You claim that

> This picture name it, from my understanding, crystal clear

And while that may be true for you, it isn't the case for anyone else. You always know what you want because you're the one that wants it. Everything is clear to you inside your own head, but that doesn't mean it is clear to us.

You need to spell everything out, in detail, **using words**. For example, tell us:

- what you want to achieve
- what the correct result would look like
- sample inputs, and expected outputs
- what the images mean
- maybe some things that you've thought about doing and why they didn't work
- any other requirements that you have (what version of R, etc., etc.)

Pictures are great, but they should be used as *supplements* to words. There are several reasons for that. Some people, like me, understand better by reading than by looking at pictures. Also, pictures are not easy for search engines to index, which makes the information contained in your question and the answers less useful to other people.

The advice given to you in the comments is good, and you should take heed of it:

> Your question hasn't been very well received here because you haven't specified exactly what you're looking for -- "I am looking for a more 'fluid' look" is hardly enough to go on. I would encourage you to do some more work in designing the sort of random setup you're looking for and then ask a question on Stack Overflow when you have a programming question about how to implement a specific, well-defined function.

Your question has one other problem, and that is that it asks for "the most effective way". What does that mean, "most effective"? What criteria are you using to judge "most effective"? Avoid using weasel words like that if you want your question to stay open and hope to get a good answer.

Comment: Dear @CodyGray in the 1st post it was signed as an "R" question.
And in R the rnorm is well known.
You can fix or handle this problem with this approach:


`a <- rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 3)
b <- rnorm(100, mean = 25, sd = 5)
c <- rnorm(100, mean = 18, sd = 1)
d <- c(a, b, c)
plot(d) `

But this is not really cool. 
What I am looking for, let me describe it with dummy-code:

`a <- rnorm(100, start_length = 20, end_length = 20, start_mean = 2.0, end_mean = 3.0 start_sd = 0.2, end_sd = 0.8) `

Comment: Hmm, okay. Yeah that's why I threw in the part about R experts being among the people who voted to close your question. You can sit here and pretend all day long that your question was clear, but that's not going to get you anywhere. If you think you can ask a new question that is sufficiently clear, then post a new question. Don't try to do it in a comment on Meta.

Comment: Thx @CodyGray. Sorry, but it was not my intention to annoy any member of  the community with my question.
However, regrettably, I'm full blocked.
It is currently not possible for me to edit a question - or post one more precise version of this random-range-definition issue/question.

Comment: @Teletubbi-OSX For what it's worth, the only interpretation of your question that made even some sense to me was answered in the comments and you responded by saying that it was close, but you needed more, in some way that was totally incomprehensible to me.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity
Confusing Stats Terms Explained: Heteroscedasticity!
http://www.statsmakemecry.com/smmctheblog/confusing-stats-terms-explained-heteroscedasticity-heteroske.html

Comment: I actually know what heteroscedasticity means. Guess I was awake that day. Didn't see that term anywhere in your original question, though, so I'm not sure what these links are intended to prove. I guess πάντα already deleted the comment you were replying to, @Teletubbi.